# Why doesn't the space show in the browser?

Tags: html

I don't know whether it is a basic question, but I need to ask.
Here is my problem, when a wrote a simple HTML code for showing a paragraph, it's not getting in the correct format that I wish.
Code below:

```
<p>
Eosinophil count - absolute
An absolute eosinophil count is a blood test that measures the number of white blood cells called eosinophils.
Eosinophils become active when you have certain allergic diseases, infections, and other medical conditions.

How the Test is Performed
Most           of the time blood is drawn from a vein on the inside of the elbow or the back of the hand. The site is cleaned with an antiseptic.
The health care provider wraps an elastic band around your upper arm to make the vein swell with blood.
Next, the provider gently inserts a needle into the vein. The blood collects into an airtight tube attached to the needle.
The elastic band is removed from your arm. The needle is then removed and the site is covered to stop bleeding.

Things to Know
In infants or young children, a sharp tool called a lancet may be used to prick the skin.
The blood collects in a small glass tube, or onto a slide or test strip. A bandage is put on the spot to stop bleeding.

Reference Range

The serum reference ranges of eosinophils are as follows:

    Eosinophils blood (%): 0.0-6.0 (This range may vary slightly in different laboratories.)
    Eosinophil blood count (absolute): 30-350. The percentage of eosinophils is multiplied by the white blood cell count to 
    give the absolute eosinophil count. This range may vary slightly in different laboratories.



ANTIGEN SUSPENSION                    SERUM DILUTION

.                                1:30     1:60    1:120    1:240   
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Salmonella Typhi "O"           :  --       --      --       --


Salmonella Typhi "H"           :  --       --      --       --


Salmonella Para Typhi "AH"     :  --       --      --       --


Salmonella Para Typhi "BH"     :  --       --      --       --


</p>
```

But in output all the spaces are truncated.
How to get the exact text as output?

[image]

Comment: In HTML spaces are always considered to be a single one no matter how many there are. Use tables or `<pre>` for preformatted text. Latter is usually not really scalable.

Answer (score 9):

Check `white-space: pre;` property in css [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

```css
p {
  white-space: pre;
 }
```

```html
<p>
Eosinophil count - absolute
An absolute eosinophil count is a blood test that measures the number of white blood cells called eosinophils.
Eosinophils become active when you have certain allergic diseases, infections, and other medical conditions.

How the Test is Performed
Most           of the time blood is drawn from a vein on the inside of the elbow or the back of the hand. The site is cleaned with an antiseptic.
The health care provider wraps an elastic band around your upper arm to make the vein swell with blood.
Next, the provider gently inserts a needle into the vein. The blood collects into an airtight tube attached to the needle.
The elastic band is removed from your arm. The needle is then removed and the site is covered to stop bleeding.

Things to Know
In infants or young children, a sharp tool called a lancet may be used to prick the skin.
The blood collects in a small glass tube, or onto a slide or test strip. A bandage is put on the spot to stop bleeding.

Reference Range

The serum reference ranges of eosinophils are as follows:

    Eosinophils blood (%): 0.0-6.0 (This range may vary slightly in different laboratories.)
    Eosinophil blood count (absolute): 30-350. The percentage of eosinophils is multiplied by the white blood cell count to 
    give the absolute eosinophil count. This range may vary slightly in different laboratories.



ANTIGEN SUSPENSION                    SERUM DILUTION

.                                1:30     1:60    1:120    1:240   
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Salmonella Typhi "O"           :  --       --      --       --


Salmonella Typhi "H"           :  --       --      --       --


Salmonella Para Typhi "AH"     :  --       --      --       --


Salmonella Para Typhi "BH"     :  --       --      --       --


</p>
```

Comment: Alternatively, use <pre>.

Answer (score 0):

use &nbsp for space in HTML